# Is there a way to act after dimension door?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, teleportation

As per dimension door:

> After using this spell, you can’t take any other actions until your next turn.

Is there a way to go around this and be able to act freely after using dimension door?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tactical feat **Sun School** (*Complete Warrior* 112) *via* the tactical maneuver flash of sunset allows a creature, after having used an effect like the spell *[dimension door](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsDtoE.html#dimension-door) et al.*, to make a single attack at the creature's highest base attack bonus against an adjacent foe.

The extraordinary ability **shadow pounce** that's a level 4 class feature of the prestige class Telflammar shadowlord (*Unapproachable East* 36-7) and a level 5 class feature of the prestige class Crinti Shadow Marauder (*Shining South* 23-4) allows the creature, after using an effect with the teleportation descriptor, to make a full attack. This is widely considered to specifically override the general limitations the spell *dimension door* describes, but be safe and ask the DM.

It's probably also worth mentioning the prestige class blade of Orien (*Dragonmarked* 99-101) which at level 10 gains the similar class feature **Orien's fury** that allows the creature to make a full attack after it uses its spell-like ability *dimensional leap* (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 66) that's granted by the creature's Mark of Passage least dragonmark.

Comment: I'll edit the question. I am trying to ask for a way that allows you to act freely after a dimension door, but this is good information

Comment: @Simon I'm not holding out on you or anything. This is—barring third party (which I haven't researched) and, maybe, some specific monsters (which I also haven't researched)—pretty much all there is.

Comment: @Simon You're welcome. I'll keep an eye out for other effects (third party and otherwise) that permit actions after a *dimension door* and update this answer when I find any, but taking actions after a *dimension door* is *so* powerful (and *dimension door* effects so readily available *via* the feat Shape Soulmeld (*blink shirt*), for example) that I can't imagine there being many other reasonable yet undiscovered options.